# preventing two instances of a java program from runnning simultaneously IN CMC

Tags: java

I have a java program scheduled in CMC but I don't want two instances of the program to run at the same time, how do i prevent that? Is it possible to achieve this via CMC configurations?

Also with java i was unable to determine if an instance of the program in currently running.

Thanks

Comment: Can you pls tell me that do you want only 1 instance of the program through out...??

Comment: check this SO link : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714234/java-if-i-have-a-instance-of-my-program-running-how-do-i-detect-that-and-then

if it hepls

Comment: @Kumar, more than one instance but only one at a time